# Using Parse.com to upload a video

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am new to parse and am trying to save and upload a video to the cloud. This is the code I am using, but it keep getting an error when the doneButtonAction is called. I believe the problem is when the video is being saved as a file, but I have no idea how to fix that. Thank you in advance -

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSLog(@"%@", videoURL);


    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (self.moviePath))
    {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (self.moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
    }

    [self shouldUploadVideo];
    [self doneButtonAction];
}

- (void)shouldUploadVideo {

    //Capturamos el NSUserdefault para grabar el evento
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"Video"];
    NSLog(@"Working at first line");



    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];
    NSLog(@"Working at second line");


    PFFile *videoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:videoData];
    NSLog(@"Working at third line");

    [self.videoFile saveInBackground];
    NSLog(@"Working at last line");

}

- (void)doneButtonAction {
    // Make sure there was no errors creating the image files
    if (!self.videoFile) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Couldn't save your photo"
                                                       message:nil
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss",nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    // Create a Photo object
    PFObject *video = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kPAPPhotoClassKey];
    [video setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey];
    [video setObject:self.videoFile forKey:@"Video"];

    // Request a background execution task to allow us to finish uploading
    // the photo even if the app is sent to the background
    self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId];
    }];

    // Save the Photo PFObject
    [video saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Photo uploaded");

            // Add the photo to the local cache
            [[PAPCache sharedCache] setAttributesForPhoto:video likers:[NSArray array] commenters:[NSArray array] likedByCurrentUser:NO];

            // Send a notification. The main timeline will refresh itself when caught
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PAPTabBarControllerDidFinishEditingPhotoNotification object:video];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Photo failed to save: %@", error);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Couldn't post your photo"
                                                            message:nil
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss",nil];
            [alert show];
        }

        // If we are currently in the background, suspend the app, otherwise
        // cancel request for background processing.
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId];
    }];

    // Dismiss this screen
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: So, in doneBottonAction, it send a message if the file hasn't been save right, and this keeps getting called @rmaddy

Comment: I'll ask again. What is the error? Post the complete error message that you get.

Comment: can someone please modify this to includea complete  Swift 3 Solutions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside

```
- (void)shouldUploadVideo {
```

you have:

```
PFFile *videoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:videoData];
NSLog(@"Working at third line");

[self.videoFile saveInBackground];
NSLog(@"Working at last line");
```

You are trying to upload **self.videoFile** in background - not **videoFile**.

This means that **videoFile** is not uploading the PFFile in the background.

Change

```
PFFile *videoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:videoData];
```

to

```
self.videoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:videoData];
```

Comment: Please note that there is a 10MB limit