# how to build a server service that supports iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm kind of familiar with building iOS applications but I need some assistance. 
I am trying to build a new application and I need some startup help:
basically, the application should have a log in screen via Facebook/google+.
A back-end server that stores data to be provided to the application's users. This server should push notifications each time a new data is uploaded to the server.
I know that the idea is so familiar and can be googled, but I need some kind of a start point, like resources, or what should I be familiar with before I start building the application. I also have no idea about the servers and how to build services.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be a beginner, I would recommend checking out [Parse](https://parse.com/products). They have a nice iOS SDK to handle cloud data storage, server processing and push notifications. Tutorials can be located [here](https://parse.com/tutorials#ios). Best of all - It's free unless you have massive traction. (Which I am assuming you don't yet)

Parse handles third party logins too. Check [this](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/bring-your-own-login/) out.

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind: I am checking the Parse website and Kind of noticed that they support only primitive data to be saved, I cannot save videos in the cloud. Am I right? and If I am, how can I save videos?

Comment: No problem! Check out this SO post in regard to video: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072988/using-parse-com-to-upload-a-video. Can you mark this as the correct answer?